# jQuery Scroll Timeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I'm trying to put a delay on page scroll so if I put some animation, it will not ruin. Here is my code:

```
var lastScrollY = 0,
    delayFlag = true,
    delayTime = 1000;

$(window).on('scroll', function(e) {
    if(delayFlag == true) {
        delayFlag = false;
        var posY = $(this).scrollTop(),
            sectionH = $('.page').height(),
            multiplier = (Math.round(lastScrollY / sectionH));

        if(lastScrollY > posY) {
            $(window).scrollTop((multiplier - 1) * sectionH);
        }
        else {
            $(window).scrollTop((multiplier + 1) * sectionH);
        }

        lastScrollY = posY;

        setTimeout(function() { delayFlag = true }, delayTime);
    }
    else {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

jQuery `preventDefault()` is not working. Is there any way I can put some delay on scroll event?

Comment: Academically speaking, this is an interesting question. UX-speaking, however, this is dodgy territory. One should not override user-expected interactions without really good reason. Users start to see your app/web page as "buggy" and "hard to use" if basic things like scrolling stop working when they get there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I wouldn't recommend this, from a UX perspective (personally, I hate pages that stop me from going someplace in the site, just so I have to watch their ad or whathaveyou, and I'm fairly sure I'm not the only one...), what you might be able to do, rather than capture the scroll event, is turn off scrolling for the area to start with.

So, have something along these lines (example jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mori57/cmLun/):

In CSS:

```
.noscroll {
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

And in your JS:

```
var lastScrollY = 0,
    delayFlag = true,
    delayTime = 1000;

$(function(){
   $("body").addClass("noscroll"); 

    window.setTimeout(function(){
        $("body").removeClass("noscroll");
    }, delayTime );
});
```

Answer (score 2):

`e.preventDefault();` is for preventing the default action of an event.  For example, clicking on an anchor will cause the page to navigate to the address stored on the anchor's href, and calling `e.preventDefault();` in an anchor's click event will cause this navigation to *not happen*.

`e.preventDefault();` does not, however, cancel the event that just occurred.  Calling it in the `onchange` event of a form input will not revert its value back to what it just was, and calling it in the scroll event will not cancel the scroll.